# Error while downloading GridLayout in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gridlayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9KeV.jpg)

I download the GridLayout and can't use it properly.

I upgraded Android Studio version and its dependencies. Still same issue. Can't see grid in my project. It is not compatible with androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1 and - androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:[2.5.1]